# Under what circumstances are edits merged together?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I made an edit to an answer I posted, and then noticed that the edit introduced a minor typo that would stop the code from working, so I did another edit that fixed the typo (deleting one character). The two edits were most likely less than a minute apart. With each edit, I used the description field to enter a description of the edit.

When I made the second edit, I noticed that the description field contained the text of my first edit's description, rather than the generic "enter an optional description of your edit here" message. But I changed it to something like "fix typo". Then, after submitting the second edit and glancing over the post, I saw that the notice at the bottom of the post said that it had been edited a double-digit number of seconds previously, which I judged to be wrong.

So I clicked on the link to my revision history, and saw that the two edits seemed to have been effectively merged together. What's more, the description field had the "fix typo" description, rather than the more informative original message. The upshot of this seeming automatic merging of edits person who makes more than one edit in quick succession may end up providing unhelpful edit descriptions without meaning to. Under what circumstances are edits merged, and what is the rationale for doing it?

Comment: Related -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322063/do-subsequent-edits-of-the-same-question-use-the-description-of-the-first-edit