# Do subsequent edits of the same question use the description of the first edit?

Tags: support, edits, edit-summary

I just edited a question twice in a very short timeframe (~10 seconds) and I don't remember having to enter a description for the edit the second time.

My question is, was the second edit merged together with the first one? If I were to look at my edit in the edit review queue, will it show one edit or two?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It will show as one edit.

There is a 5 minute "grace period" when editing. Changes made within these 5 minutes are merged into the same edit.

There is an exception, which is when someone comments on the post. That terminates the "grace period" and further edits will count as new ones.

Edits made during the "grace period" are sometimes called "ninja edits" because the original edit doesn't show up in the revision history; only the combined edit can be seen.

Comment: "Ninja edits" also apply to edits made within 5 minutes of post creation.  In that case, the post won't show as edited at all.

Comment: I prefer to think of them as a friendly `git rebase` of my branch before a push... only, not actually before.